# Eclipse Plug-in Development - Build Issue

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, xpages

I am quite new to developing plugins with Eclipse and wondered if anyone can help me with an issue or pointers as to where I am going wrong. I am trying to compile a plugin for use in a Lotus Notes Update Site DB for XPages.

I downloaded the plugin code from:
https://github.com/timtripcony/oauth4domino/tree/master

Then I imported it into my plugin project in Eclipse and it doesn't appear to be building because when I view the original developers video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxpTdbsuMaE at 10:44 he has the "Features" & "Plugins" folders and some jar files and I can't get mine to build them. Or am I doing something wrong?

Developers Eclipse Environment
[image]

My Eclipse Environment (Update Site greyed out and no Features or Plugings folders) Build All doesn't seem to build anything.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site.xml isn't mapping to the feature correctly (it's showing greyed out).

The feature.xml in the Feature project (`org.openntf.xsp.oauth.feature`) picks up the plugin (or plugins - it can include multiple) project (`org.openntf.xsp.oauth.library`). The site.xml in the Update Site project (`org.openntf.xsp.oauth.update`) points to the feature (or features) project.

The version number of the feature may have changed. Delete it from the site.xml, then highlight the category and select "Add Feature..." and select the feature. Then you should be able to build it.

Comment: My project was set up wrong. I re imported them and viola. Thanks for the help it pushed me in the right direction.